# How can I convert 'System.Windows.Input.Key' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm developing application in WPF but some components are written using WinForms. I wan't these components to pull key gesture from WPF part and convert them to Keys enum (used in WinForms).

Is there a built in converter for that? (probably not)
Do you know "easier than big switch case" method to do that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
Keys formsKey = ...;
Key wpfKey = ...;
wpfKey = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey((int)formsKey);
formsKey = (Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
```

The [KeyInterop class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.aspx) is the "key," plus the fact that the Windows Forms `Keys` enumeration has the same integer values as the Win 32 virtual key codes.

Comment: What about modifiers (Alt, Control, Shift)?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case people still encounter the modifier problem 7 years later, here's my solution that worked so far :

```cs
public static class KeyEventExts
{
    public static System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs ToWinforms(this System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        // So far this ternary remained pointless, might be useful in some very specific cases though
        var wpfKey = keyEventArgs.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.System ? keyEventArgs.SystemKey : keyEventArgs.Key;
        var winformModifiers = keyEventArgs.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.ToWinforms();
        var winformKeys = (System.Windows.Forms.Keys)System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
        return new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs(winformKeys | winformModifiers);
    }

    public static System.Windows.Forms.Keys ToWinforms(this System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys modifier)
    {
        var retVal = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None;
        if(modifier.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Alt))
        {
            retVal |= System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Alt;
        }
        if (modifier.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            retVal |= System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control;
        }
        if (modifier.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.None))
        {
            // Pointless I know
            retVal |= System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None;
        }
        if (modifier.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Shift))
        {
            retVal |= System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift;
        }
        if (modifier.HasFlag(System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Windows))
        {
            // Not supported lel
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert modifiers, use the SystemKey if you're looking at a KeyEventArgs:

```
System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs args;
System.Windows.Input.Key wpfKey= args.Key == Key.System ? args.SystemKey : args.Key;
formsKey = (System.Windows.Forms.Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off Sam Harwell's excellent answer to take modifiers into account, if you're wanting to go from wpf to winforms and want to include modifier keys you can do this:

```
Keys formsKey = ...;
System.Windows.Input.Key wpfKey = ...;

wpfKey = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey((int)formsKey);
formsKey = (Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);

if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftShift) ||
    System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.RightShift))
    formsKey |= Keys.Shift;
if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftAlt) ||
    System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.RightAlt))
    formsKey |= Keys.Alt;
if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.LeftCtrl) ||
    System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.RightCtrl))
    formsKey |= Keys.Control;
```

Or if you wanted to go from winforms to wpf:

```
var isShift = (keys & Keys.LShiftKey) == Keys.LShiftKey || (keys & Keys.RShiftKey) == Keys.RShiftKey;
var isAlt = (keys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt;
var isCtrl = (keys & Keys.LControlKey) == Keys.LControlKey || (keys & Keys.RControlKey) == Keys.RControlKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the [WPF `Key` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=netframework-4.8#fields) to the corresponding [WinForms `Keys` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8#fields) use the static member [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) of the `Enum` class:

`Enum.TryParse(wpfKeyEnum.ToString(), out System.Windows.Forms.Keys winFormsKeyEnum)`

WPF modifiers [(ModifierKeys enumeration)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.8) can be converted the same way except the Windows key. In contrast to the `Windows.Input.ModifierKeys` enumeration of WPF the `Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration distinguishes between left and right Windows keys and defines corresponding `LWin` an `RWin` fields.

This conversion method works in both directions.

### Example

The example converts the `Key` and `ModifierKeys` enumerations of a WPF key up event to the corresponding WinForms `Keys` enumeration.

**From `Windows.Input.Key` To `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`**

```
private void OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
  // Convert key
  if (Enum.TryParse(e.Key.ToString(), out System.Windows.Forms.Keys winFormsKey))
  {
    MessageBox.Show(winFormsKey + "=" + (int) winFormsKey); // A=65
  }
}
```

**From `Windows.Input.ModifierKeys` To `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`**

```
private void OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
  ModifierKeys modifiers = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers;

  IEnumerable<ModifierKeys> pressedModifierKeys  = Enum.GetValues(modifiers.GetType())
    .Cast<ModifierKeys>()
    .Where(modifiers.HasFlag);

  // The ModifierKeys enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute
  foreach (ModifierKeys modifier in pressedModifierKeys)
  {
    if (Enum.TryParse(modifier.ToString(), out System.Windows.Forms.Keys winFormsModifierKey))
    {
      MessageBox.Show(winFormsModifierKey + "=" + (int) winFormsModifierKey); // Alt=262144
    }
  }
}
```