# Convert KeyEventArgs to KEYDBINPUT struct

Tags: c#, sendinput, keyeventargs

I am working on a networked system (in C#) where on one computer I receive keyboard input via a low level hook and then transmit the input to another computer where it has to be injected.

The hook delivers the keyboard input in a KeyEventArgs class.
To inject it into the target computer I need to use a KEYBDINPUT struct with SendInput.

There does not seem to be an easy match between KeyEventArgs.KeyCode or KeyValue and
KEYBDINPUT.wVk and wScan. I also tried MapVirtualKey in some combinations.

Alternatively, I could convert KeyEventArgs into windows key messages (WM_KEYUP/DOWN with wParam and lParam) on the source computer but I am facing similar difficulties.

Can anybody here help out with either scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/sending-windows-key-using-sendkeys/10367832#10367832) where I suggest the use of [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) as an alternative to other low level work. This uses the `Win32 SendInput` API directly.

This uses `VirtualKeyCode`, so since you have `KeyEventArgs` you can just use the `KeyValue` property:

InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(keyEventArgs.KeyValue);

If you only have a `System.Key` you can convert to a `VirtualKey`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey.aspx

[How can I convert 'System.Windows.Input.Key' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys)