# Sending Windows key using SendKeys

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys

I am working on shortcuts in C#. I succeed implementing Ctrl, Alt and Shift with SendKeys.

Like this;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
```

or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
```

But I can't send "Windows Key" with SendKeys. I tried ex: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> : `.SendWait("#e")` but it's not working. What should I use instead of "#"?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows key is actually equivalent of a `CTRL + ESC`, have you tried with that?

Comment: Seconded. It is SendSystemKeys "{Ctrl+Esc}"

Comment: Yes, I tried that with .SendWait("^{ESC}") but that's not working too. Is there any wrong code in this syntax?

Comment: Process.Start("explorer.exe");

Comment: Win + E , is just a sample. Imagine that, I will need Win + R (Run) or Win + L.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK turns out what you really want is this: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Which has done all the hard work of exposing the `Win32 SendInput` methods to C#. This allows you to directly send the windows key. This is tested and works:

`InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);`

**Note** however that in some cases you want to specifically send the key to the application (such as `ALT+F4`), in which case use the `Form` library method. In others, you want to send it to the OS in general, use the above.

---

**Old**

Keeping this here for reference, it will not work in all operating systems, and will not always behave how you want. Note that you're trying to send these key strokes to the app, and the OS usually intercepts them early. In the case of Windows 7 and Vista, too early (before the `E` is sent).

`SendWait("^({ESC}E)")` or `Send("^({ESC}E)")`

Note from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

> To specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held
>   down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those
>   keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E and C are pressed, use "+(EC)". To specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E is pressed, followed by C without SHIFT, use "+EC".

Note that since you want `ESC` and (say) `E` pressed at the same time, you need to enclose them in brackets.

Comment: Cool, your gravatar is almost identical to the OPs. :-P

Comment: Here is what I really want it. Many thanks for your reply, very grateful!

Comment: input simulator requires you to reference the Dll in excel right?

Comment: How to send the key for one specific window? For example, i want to send the Winkey to an aplication that's in full screen and its active. It isn't working the way i need. Thank you!

Comment: Last maintained fork: https://github.com/GregsStack/InputSimulatorStandard

Answer (score 9):

download InputSimulator from [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/).

then write this:

```
        var simu = new InputSimulator();
        simu.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);
```

in my case to create new vertial desktop, 3 keys needed and code like this(windows key + ctrl + D):

```
        simu.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(new[] { VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL }, VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
```

Comment: Any idea how to use this in PowerShell , via Add-Type ?

Comment: please see this page:https://github.com/TChatzigiannakis/InputSimulatorPlus/blob/master/WindowsInput.Tests/InputSimulatorExamples.cs you can run run command and then in run type any app name and then do every thing you want.

Comment: for example: var sim = new InputSimulator();
            sim.Keyboard
               .ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_R)
               .Sleep(1000)
               .TextEntry("notepad")
               .Sleep(1000)
               .KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN)
               .Sleep(1000)
               .TextEntry("These...")
               .TextEntry("and in 5 seconds.")
               .Sleep(5000)
               .ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.MENU, VirtualKeyCode.SPACE)
               .KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN)
.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

Answer (score 7):

Alt+F4 is working only in brackets

```
SendKeys.SendWait("(%{F4})");
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect. 
Discovery: If you want to send alt+letter. If I use lower case letter (ex alt+w,  "(%{w})"), it works fine. But if I use uppercase letter (ex alt+W) windows forms consumes the Alt to select the form menustrip first-item and the key combo fails. This is on .Net 4.8

Answer (score 2):

```
SetForegroundWindow( /* window to gain focus */ );
SendKeys.SendWait("^{ESC}"); // ^{ESC} is code for ctrl + esc which mimics the windows key.
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending combination of  Ctrl+Alt+Right ==> use this ==> "(^%({RIGHT}))"