# VBScript SendKeys CTRL+LWIN+TAB?

Tags: windows, vbscript, sendkeys, keystroke

I am trying to write a simple script that will send the key combo of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WINDOWS KEY</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. The code below sends the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"
```

However when I try to replace "%" (aka the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key) with <kbd>LWIN</kbd> (aka the Left Windows Key) it says Syntax Error.

I tried the following, but had no luck:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.SendKeys "^{LWIN}{TAB}"
```

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.SendKeys "^{LWIN}+{TAB}"
```

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.SendKeys ^{LWIN}+{TAB}
```

I know it has something to do with being able to Hold certain keys while other keys are pressed but I can't seem to get it right.

The windows key can be pressed programmatically using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>. Is there a way to set this combination as a variable called <kbd>LWIN</kbd> and then use one of the above Scripts?

Comment: It is a dinosaur-and-humans time anachronism.  VBScript was invented long before keyboards got a Windows key.  Or perhaps more appropriately, they stopped maintaining VBScript a long, long time ago.  Back in the previous century.  Not supported in .NET's SendKeys either, look at something like AutoHotkey.

Comment: I don't see how this could be true if there are people out there with guides on how to do key combinations such as WINDOWS KEY + X or WINDOWS KEY + M.

Comment: The windows key is simulated with CTRL+ESC (Refer to update above)

Comment: Ctrl+Esc doesn't simulate the Win key; it just calls the Start menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case someone land here on these years...
A workaround (instead of sending keystrokes) is to call directly to the application:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.WindowSwitcher
```

This will open `Task Switcher` Windows App. (Same as <kbd>⊞ windows</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>)

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "+(^{LWIN}{TAB})"
```

Comment: doesn't work in win11

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for VBscript but it looks like that is unlikely (pure VBscript).  Here is a post that did solve this via C#.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367832/1742115

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-function-from-vbscript) tells how to call the C# DLL from your VBscript if you want to keep some of this in vbs.

Comment: Ok that could work but is it possible to run the proposed code without a gui? therefore acting like vbscript (Pure action and no visual evidence). my intention is to create a small script that will simulate the windows 3D Task Switcher. (Represented by CTRL+WIN+TAB)

Comment: [This page](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/), which contains the code, says it can be run as a console application... so no UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/131247) and what you actually want to do is to activate Flip 3D (Switch between windows). You can do this programmatically by executing the `rundll32 DwmApi #105` command:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "rundll32 DwmApi #105"
```