# VBScript SendKeys CTRL+SHIFT+B or DwmApi # associated with this combination?

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I'm looking for some vbs script or shortcut for opening Outlook Address Book (keyboard shortcut: CTRL+SHIFT+B),or it can be DwmApi # associated with this combination?
Found similar discussion here: [VBScript SendKeys CTRL+LWIN+TAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877547/vbscript-sendkeys-ctrllwintab-updated)
Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for this:

```
set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
ol.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog.Display
```

Comment: sorry, but checked again and it's almost what I need... when i'm using CTRL+SHIFT+B combination, GAL window appears without To, Cc and Bcc fields, so when I'm searching for the user, by double click afer i've find  it,  it shows his properties and not add it to the "To" filed... So i'm need the script will open the GAL in the same way as if I'm using CTRL+SHIFT+B combination.

Comment: These fields are displayed only when you're composing a message, regardless of how you open the address book.

Comment: When I'm using script, you're provided it looks like in the screen bellow:

Comment: And when I'm using CTRL+SHIFT+B combination it looks different:

Comment: I'm aware of what the address book looks like. Read again.

Comment: First of all shank for you'r help!! May be I'm didn't explain my needs properly... I need some quick way to find user alias from outlook 2013.

Comment: So the quickest way to do it is create some script for quickly open Outlook GAL, search the user by user id, double click on user  and user properties window will poup with all relevant information. In the script, you're provided (thanks again) when I'm searching the user by his ID it found it, but when I'm clicking on it it just add the user to the "To" filed (like I want send the email) instead of open user properties. I can open user properties by right click on the user >> properties, but is no so suitable.... When I'm using CTRL + Shift + B keys it working as expected.

Comment: I hope it is clear now. trying to use send keys method:

Comment: set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys ("^+{B}")
WScript.Quit() but it's not working