# activate task view programmatically windows 10

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-10

Is there a way to activate task view programmatically in windows 10?

There was a way to activate Flip3D programmatically in win7 using the following copied from [VBScript SendKeys CTRL+LWIN+TAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877547/vbscript-sendkeys-ctrllwintab-updated)

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "rundll32 DwmApi #105"
```

I just want to make a .vbs or .bat file that activates windows 10 Task View.

Answer (score 1):

OK Found a way to do it with C#

1. Install Visual studio
2. Install NuGet http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget
3. File > New Project
4. Name it taskview
5. Visual C# > Console application
6. File > Save All
7. Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
8. Type "Install-Package InputSimulator" in Package Manager console
   window
9. Paste Following text in taskview.cs window

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using WindowsInput.Native;// Importante

   namespace taskview
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               WindowsInput.InputSimulator kb = new WindowsInput.InputSimulator();
               kb.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
               Console.Read();// Keep console window open
           }
       }
   }
   ```
10. Change Dropdown with Debug in it to Release
11. Build > Build Solution
12. Build > Build taskview

It should be in: My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\taskview\taskview\bin\Release\taskview.exe

Comment: I just did this without the need of installing full visual studio (but I had .net framework installed).
What I did was to run `dotnet new console -n taskview`. Then it creates a .net project with name taskview. After that, I paste your code into Program.cs and then I install InputSimulator in the project by running `dotnet add package InputSimulator --version 1.0.4`. Then just `dotnet build -c release` and you will find the taskview.exe in the bin/release folder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function having the ordinal 105 within dwmapi.dll. You can use rundll32.exe to execute that function. This is how the command line looks like:
start rundll32.exe dwmapi.dll #105

It will trigger the Flip 3D functionality on Windows Vista and later, if Aero is enabled.