# How do I use the sendkeys.send to work with the windows key

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, voice-recognition, sendkeys

I'm trying to make a software in c# that needs to sendkeys.send the windows key and l how would i do this ive tried sendkeys.send(keys.lwin); but that doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Windows key using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/sending-windows-key-using-sendkeys)

Comment: no this doesnt i does tell me how to do it. it just tells me about control & alt

Comment: Read the answers more closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Here is a workaround that you can use the key combination `Ctrl + Esc` to replace `Windows Key`. The following is a simple demo.</s>

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^{ESC}");
}
```

Hope this can help you.

---

**Modified:**

If you want to lock the PC via code, you can call `LockWorkStation function`.

```
[DllImport("user32 ")]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LockWorkStation();
}
```

Besides, if you want achieve `Win+D`, `Win+E`, etc., you can try the following code.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(Byte bVk, Byte bScan, Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dwExtraInfo);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keybd_event(0x5b, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(68, 0, 0, 0); // D is 68, and E is 69
    keybd_event(0x5b, 0, 0x2, 0);
    keybd_event(68, 0, 0x2, 0);
}
```

Comment: this would not work due to that only shows up the search bar and i dont want it to do that i want it so that i can lock my screen using it

Comment: I have modified my answer, you can check it.

Comment: The top one works super thank you so much for the help

Comment: @MEZYPLAYS I am glad this answer can help you. Maybe you can click `√` to accept the answer.