# what is the correct syntax for SendKeys of Shift + Win + V?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sendkeys

So I wanted to close toast notification.

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> move the focus to the notification.
2. Then, <kbd>Delete</kbd> to dismiss it

I am wondering if C# or VB.net can achieve this without using 3rd party library, so I tried:

`SendKeys.SendWait("+(^{v})")`

and
`SendKeys.SendWait("+(^{V})")`

neither works for casing of `v`, what's wrong? Which syntax is written correctly?
I logged it with KeyEventArgs but seems like it didn't send the Windows Key. I tried `SendKeys.SendWait("+(^{ESC}v)")` but it opened task manager instead

Comment: sure they can every key has a numric code and you can join them with and, to catch if they where preseed

Comment: right now I have no idea how to log or see which key is pressed, on screen keyboard is not showing anything

Comment: forms have a key_down, witch catch every keysroke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/sending-windows-key-using-sendkeys

Comment: I don't want to use 3rd party library thought

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Windows key using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366152/sending-windows-key-using-sendkeys)

Comment: @KenWhite no it doesn't I tried it, it didn't execute the win key, I logged it with KeyEventArgs as well