# How to adapt WPF KeyEventArgs to Winforms KeyEventArgs?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert 'System.Windows.Input.Key' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys)

I have a WPF control that has object of type **System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs**. The control needs to pass that object to a method that expects a **System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs**.

Is there a built-in **adapter** (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) in the .Net Windows Forms Integration classes to do that? Or do I have to code the adapter (including a huge switch case to map each value of System.Windows.Input.Key to the corresponding value in System.Windows.Forms.Keys)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys

Comment: @AS-CII: That link answers a part of my question and addresses the `Input.Key` to `Forms.Keys` mapping. But it does not address all the things that must be adapted. For instance, if the method that takes a `Forms.KeyEventArgs` sets the `Handeled` property to True, a good adapter would affect that same property on the adapted `Input.KeyEventArgs` object.

Comment: You should have used this info to edit your question.  Claiming that you need help with assigning a bool property named Handled from a bool property that has the same name and description doesn't get you an answer.

Comment: @Hans: I'm looking for an adaptor to wrap an Input.KeyEventArgs and expose it at Forms.KeyEventArgs. "Adapting" and "converting" are two very different things (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). An adaptor is an active object that forwards all calls to the adapted object. If there is no such thing in .Net, then the answer to my question is: No there is no such adapter in .Net, you have to build your own.