# Convert Key to Keys in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use the new **Key** Enumeration in my ObjectModel to avoid having a reference to Windows.Forms in this Dll. The GUI uses a class library that wants the **Keys** enumeration.

Is it possible in any way to convert a **Key** value to a **Keys** value?

EDIT: I just found out that my question was already asked and answered here: [How can I convert 'System.Windows.Input.Key' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys)

Comment: Are you asking how to convert between two different enumerations? One approach is to do it through casting to an int and then back to the other enum.

Comment: @Bernard Chen no that doesn't work. A Key doesn't have the same numerical value as a Keys

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's not something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey.aspx) to convert to a Win32 key, and then directly cast to winforms Keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you want to use a type declared in another assembly, in your case the enum, you should copy the whole definition in your own assembly, basically declaring it again.

what is worse then? having a cloned declaration or referencing windows.forms.dll ?