# Global hotkeys in WPF working from every window

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

I have to use hotkeys which will be working from every window and pulpit. In winforms I used:

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 9000, 0x0002, (int)Keys.F10);
```

and

```
UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 9000);
```

and

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case 0x312:
        switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            case 9000:
            //function to do
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

In my WPF aplication I tried do:

```
AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);
```

and

```
private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F11 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        //function to do
    }
}
```

But it works only when my application is active and on the top, but it doesn't work when the application is minimized (for example). Is any method to do it?

Comment: What does 9000 stand for?

Comment: Ah got it from these comments in this example: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/573/how-to-register-a-single-or-multiple-global-hotkeys-for-a-single-key-in-winforms

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in WinForms with some adaptation:

- use `WindowInteropHelper` to get `HWND` (instead of `Handle` property of a form)
- use `HwndSource` to handle window messages (instead of overriding `WndProc` of a form)
- don't use `Key` enumeration from `WPF` - it's values are not the ones you want

Complete code:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] int id,
    [In] uint fsModifiers,
    [In] uint vk);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] int id);

private HwndSource _source;
private const int HOTKEY_ID = 9000;

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
    _source.AddHook(HwndHook);
    RegisterHotKey();
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    _source.RemoveHook(HwndHook);
    _source = null;
    UnregisterHotKey();
    base.OnClosed(e);
}

private void RegisterHotKey()
{
    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    const uint VK_F10 = 0x79;
    const uint MOD_CTRL = 0x0002;
    if(!RegisterHotKey(helper.Handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CTRL, VK_F10))
    {
        // handle error
    }
}

private void UnregisterHotKey()
{
    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    UnregisterHotKey(helper.Handle, HOTKEY_ID);
}

private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_HOTKEY:
            switch(wParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case HOTKEY_ID:
                    OnHotKeyPressed();
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private void OnHotKeyPressed()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You can use KeyInterop on WPF keys to get the correct virtual key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys .