# WPF Global Hotkeys / Global Hook Keystrokes

Tags: c#, wpf, keystroke, global-hotkey

First, I would like to know what is the difference between Global Hotkeys and Hook Global Keystrokes and using them as hotkeys?

Second, I wan to use Global Hotkeys in my application, it will have 2 parts:
1. I will make a window that shows the user what keys he's pressing right now, with KeyUp function, it will save the combination.
2. When the combination from step 1 is pressed, it will call specific function

The user can have several hotkeys combinations at the same time, each hotkeys combination call DIFFERENT function.

I found lots of solutions/explanations/whatever in the internet but I don't know which will be the best for my needs - here's where I need your help.

**Here are some (maybe all) of the solutions/explanations/whatever I found:**

[Using global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) in WPF / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp)

https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/274003/Global-Hotkeys-in-WPF

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html

[How can I register a global hot key to say CTRL+SHIFT+(LETTER) using WPF and .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne)

[Global hotkeys in WPF working from every window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377977/global-hotkeys-in-wpf-working-from-every-window)

Would appreciate your help