# C# Detect KeyDown when the WinForm is not in front

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I am trying to use the keyDown method (Ctrl + R) to record the mouse position on the screen.
It works perfect when the Form is in front but when I click outside the form, the form turns gray, go to the back and stop the keyDown detection.
A label in the form keeps showing the mouse position even when the form is in the back but the keyDown doesn't work. 
Obviously I know it is the normal action of windows to prioritize the software which is in front and in use but 
is there a way to make the keyDown method works even when the form is not in front or when the form is minimized.
Thanks in advance and I am welcome to any comment, idea or suggestion.

**Update**: Thanks to the replies I got the answer. I got a library for Global Hotkeys and LowLevelHooks from here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

Comment: I think [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785375/c-sharp-wpf-catch-keydown-even-when-minimized) can help you. I used it a while ago for WPF application but it should be identical for WinForms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is global keyboard hooks which is used to detect keys outside winform you can check this link for code example 
[Keyboard Hook in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check