# WPF - Assigning Global hotkeys in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to implement global hotkeys (activated even without focus on the form) in WPF but using VB.NET.  There are a lot of examples around using C# but I have tried for hours to convert these and have failed to get anything to work.

I used to have them working in WinForms using RegisterHotkey but there is no Wndproc anymore in WPF...

Basically I just want a hotkey such as Alt+A to run a Private Sub in my code behind.

If anyone could help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Wally

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp ?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have done it!  Adding a global hotkey using WPF and VB.NET can be done by adding these references (Mainwindow.xmal.vb):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Interop
```

Then adding the following to the Code behind:

```
<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function RegisterHotKey(<[In]> hWnd As IntPtr, <[In]> id As Integer, <[In]> fsModifiers As UInteger, <[In]> vk As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(<[In]> hWnd As IntPtr, <[In]> id As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Private _source As HwndSource
Private Const HOTKEY_ID As Integer = 9000

Protected Overrides Sub OnSourceInitialized(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnSourceInitialized(e)
    Dim helper = New WindowInteropHelper(Me)
    _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle)
    _source.AddHook(AddressOf HwndHook)
    RegisterHotKey()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(e As EventArgs)
    _source.RemoveHook(AddressOf HwndHook)
    _source = Nothing
    UnregisterHotKey()
    MyBase.OnClosed(e)
End Sub

Private Sub RegisterHotKey()
    Dim helper = New WindowInteropHelper(Me)
    Const VK_F10 As UInteger = &H79
    Const MOD_CTRL As UInteger = &H2
    ' handle error
    If Not RegisterHotKey(helper.Handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CTRL, VK_F10) Then
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UnregisterHotKey()
    Dim helper = New WindowInteropHelper(Me)
    UnregisterHotKey(helper.Handle, HOTKEY_ID)
End Sub

Private Function HwndHook(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr
    Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
    Select Case msg
        Case WM_HOTKEY
            Select Case wParam.ToInt32()
                Case HOTKEY_ID
                    OnHotKeyPressed()
                    handled = True
                    Exit Select
            End Select
            Exit Select
    End Select
    Return IntPtr.Zero
End Function

Private Sub OnHotKeyPressed()
    MsgBox("Hello world!")
End Sub
```

This is for Ctrl+F10.  It can be changed by modifying the following according to Keycodes from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Key modifiers from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Just replace the 0x with &H.

```
    Const VK_F10 As UInteger = &H79
    Const MOD_CTRL As UInteger = &H2
```

Hope this helps someone.  Credit goes to "max" from which the code was converted:
[Global hotkeys in WPF working from every window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377977/global-hotkeys-in-wpf-working-from-every-window)

Answer (score 1):

> there is no Wndproc anymore in WPF...

Actually, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf) ;)

For global hotkeys, you can use my [NHotkey library](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey), which has bindings for WPF and WinForms. The examples are in C#, but you can easily convert them to VB.NET.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your reply.  I have tried your NHotkey library previously but failed to get it to work, but it seems I gave up too soon.  I have tried it just again now however I get the error "Error 5 Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Function OnIncrement(sender As Object, e As NHotkey.HotkeyEventArgs) As Object'." As well as for e.....

Comment: @WallyCloud, I don't understand what the error message means in this case, but it should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your help.  I had to have a function otherwise it would give the error "Does not return a value".  I also tried with the keybinding xaml option "HotkeyManager.RegisterGlobalHotkey but it would only register when the form was in focus.  Maybe an issue with how I set up my commands.  But anyway :) I managed to find a solution.  Thank you!

Comment: @WallyCloud, *I had to have a function otherwise it would give the error "Does not return a value"* : there must be something wrong in your code, because the delegate passed to AddOrReplace isn't supposed to return a value...