# How to use Keyboard events to stop a Timer in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, visual-studio-2017, keyboard

I want to stop a timer which is running in my Windows Form by pressing any key from the keyboard.
Do you have any idea ?

For example, inside my Form, I am trying this :

```
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
myTimer.Interval = 400;
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
{
    if (myTimer.Enabled)
         myTimer.Stop();
}
```

The problem is even I have already added the assembly **PresentationCore.dll** but **Keyboard** in the code above is not recognized. And I'am facing this error:

!!! "the name keyboard does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Your question should be how to listen for keyboard events, this is most definitely a duplicate

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have changed the title. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the reference `WindowsBase.dll`.

And check it in timer handler.

```
int i = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i++);

    if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter))
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Timer Stopped");
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Still having this error:
the type or namespace name keyboard does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Input'

Comment: @VanMinhNhonTRUONG I added the reference `WindowsBase` and `PresentationCore` , and it works fine on several machines. Did you add them by steps `Project` => `Add Reference...`?

Comment: @VanMinhNhonTRUONG Ought to be `PresentationCore`, rather than `System.Windows.Presentation`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add KeyPressEventHandler in your Form's constructor and stop the timer in this handler. This code assumes `myTimer` is accessible in OnKeyPress e.g. is a private field of this Form.

Read more in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level).

```
public MyForm
{
    this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(OnKeyPress);
}

void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTimer.Enabled)
         myTimer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. But if my form is not the first app displayed on the desktop, this does not work because we do not press the key on the form...

Comment: That's correct. Then things get a little more complicated and you have to register a global hotkey like in [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerhotkey.html) article. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377977/global-hotkeys-in-wpf-working-from-every-window) is some question related to WinForms directly.

Comment: Ya it seems more quite complicated... I'm trying another method to do this (e.g. by using another timer). thanks so much!