# How to use WndProc in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I know there have been quite a lot of questions about this answered here, but I can't understand what to do, since I am still a beginner in programming. So I have code that works as a global keyhook that works in WinForms. It detects when F9 is pressed even when app is minimized. But when rewriting code to wpf, i have some troubles with `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`. Every other piece of code that is required I solved the error. Below are snippets of my code.

`using System.Windows.Interop;`

```
// 2. Import the RegisterHotKey Method
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
```

In the constructor:

```
// 3. Register HotKey
int UniqueHotkeyId = 1;
int HotKeyCode = (int)0x78;
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
Boolean F9Registered = RegisterHotKey(windowHandle, UniqueHotkeyId, 0x0000, HotKeyCode);
```

And the part where the errors are:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // 5. Catch when a HotKey is pressed!
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
    {
        int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
        
        if (id == 1)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
    
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Errors are at:
`protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`
and
`base.WndProc(ref m);`

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: `WndProc()` is not a method of `Sytem.Windows.Window`, so you cannot override it, nor call the base method, as it does not exist. I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11378213/3220898) can solve your problem.

Comment: @Arkane thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out, but I can't get it to work. I don't know how to set a hotkey or get a hotkey_id.

Comment: Edit: I got it to work

Comment: Agree with @Arkane. `protected virtual void WndProc(ref Message m)` is a leftover method from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class. `Sytem.Windows.Window` class does not have this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with the help of Arkane's answer. But the example code that worked is located here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/