# Key conversion code

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, key, type-conversion

I asked a question earlier this day and that guy referred me to this topic: [How can I convert 'System.Windows.Input.Key' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153009/how-can-i-convert-system-windows-input-key-to-system-windows-forms-keys)

But since that topic is quite old, I assumed asking it here would be better.
I got this code and I need it to convert me Keys, but I can't for the life of me understand what the code does.

```
Keys formsKey = ...;
Key wpfKey = ...;
wpfKey = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey((int)formsKey);
formsKey = (Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
```

to be clear, I need to have a key conversion for this:

```
private void movement(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs key)
    {
        if (wpfKey = Keys.Up)
        {
            x -= 20;
        } ...
```

So how exactly would that first code work in the second?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```cs
private void movement(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs key)
    {
        if ((Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key) == Keys.Up)
        {
            x -= 20;
        } ...
```